# What (are we supposed to believe) did the Yakamoz fire at?

Tags: yakamoz-s-245, into-the-night

During season 1 of [*Yakamoz S-245*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Into_the_Deep_(TV_series)) (2022), Umut fires two torpedoes while he is in command of the Yakamoz. He tries to keep this a secret from the scientists.

A definitive answer of what those torpedoes hit is probably subject of any future seasons of this series or any other series set in the same universe. But that's not what I'm asking about:

The way it was presented, I think the series meant to insinuate the torpedoes had a particular target, known to us spectators. However, I'm confused. Which target is that? I somewhat guess it might add up with any of the events from *Into the Night*, but the only sudden destruction by an unknown force I remember from there were destroyed planes. Planes, standing on the ground. As opposed to anything that could be hit by torpedoes.

##### Did the series authors mean to imply a certain target of those torpedoes? Or am I mistaken and it is just an open mystery at this point?

Comment: They were missiles, not torpedoes, and the implication is that they were indeed fired by Umut and caused the destruction of the Russian planes and/or the airport.

Comment: @WolfieSmith: You may want to post that as an answer, in particular if you have some reference (e.g. a citation from the show - the original text + translation) that "they were missiles, not torpedoes". I'll have to re-check, but I think the German subtitles always said "torpedoes" - which may well have been a mistranslation from Turkish, though.

Comment: English dub and subtitles say 'missiles', Turkish subtitles say 'fuzeleri', which is Turkish for missiles. Sorry, it's just a bad translation issue.

Comment: @WolfieSmith: Yes, well, then write that as an answer, please.

Comment: @WolfieSmith: And actually, while it may be somewhat off-topic for this site (or is it, if it serves to corroborate the answer?), I wasn't aware missiles work like that. What the crewmen were cleaning looked like the forward/rearward-facing (?) torpedo launch tubes; I was not aware those tubes can be used to launch missiles that will then become airborne - but I am by no means knowledgeable about submarine weapon systems, so ...

Comment: not sure what missiles they were on the show, but some cruise missiles can be fired from horizontal torpedo tubes. The Tomahawk is a perfect example.

Comment: your welcome to put this info together and answer your own question, btw

Answer (score 1):

This is what happened:
Umut bombed the Russian and the NATO bunker.
If you watched Into The Night, you’ll see that the Russian and the NATO bunker airport has been destroyed by unknown people.
But what is more interesting is that in Season 2 Episode 6 of Into the Night, approximately 21:42 minute, you will see the same submarine that the Yakamoz S-245 submarine going to the seeds just like the people in Into The Night. That means, Umut has indeed bombed Russian Bunker and the NATO bunker. The end of Yakamoz S245 is in the arctics, chasing the seed. And this is exactly where Yakamoz S245 people are colliding and coming across Into the Night people if that makes sense.